# Can I count the no. of columns in an access database?

Tags: c#

I want to find the no. of columns in a given table in a database.

For counting the no. of rows I use the following query:

```
string commandParam = string.Format("select count(*) from {0}",tableName);
```

I was wondering if there was a similar query for finding the no. of columns.
I'm working with tables which have different no. of columns.

Also could anybody point me to where I can learn to use the Select Query

Thanks

EDIT: This is the code I'm using to read information in each column

```
using (readNext = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (readNext.Read())
  {
     for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)  // Where I am iterating throught each column
     {
       var nextValue = readNext.GetValue(x);
       // Code
     }
  }
}
```

I want to have it so if the no. of columns changes I can still iterate through the columns and then move onto the next row

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/  If you created the table, how can you not know how many columns there are?

Comment: You need to execute the query.

Comment: there are other (better) ways to read data from a query.  use `ExecuteReader` to fill a datatable for instance

Comment: what about `dt.Columns.Count()`?

Comment: Access, Should really be 0 in todays day and age. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

In Access, you can't do it directly. You'll need the following VBA script:

```
Function FieldCount(ByVal TableName As String) As Long
    Dim recordSet As DAO.Recordset
    Set recordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(TableName, dbOpenSnapshot)
    FieldCount = recordSet.Fields.Count
    recordSet.Close
    Set recordSet = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way in mssql.

```
  SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'database' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'table'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a VBA solution?

```
Function FieldCount(TableName As String) As Byte
FieldCount = CurrentDb.TableDefs(TableName).Fields.Count
End Function
```

On your Form put this:

```
=FieldCount("TableName")
```